# SMS and Email Security

Tags: java, security, email, sms

In my java web application, when an admin adds a user, my system generates a random alphanumeric string activation key of length 12.

This key gets divided into 2 parts, each of length 6. One part of the activation key is sent via the users Mobile with SMS and the second part is sent via Email to the user's Email ID.

I was told, that SMS and Email can be easily hacked, so if you're sending your activation key through SMS and Email, a hacker can easily retrieve it.

- What should i do to solve this problem?
- Is SMS and Email secure?
- Is there any third party Security I can use?
- How do other websites send their email and SMS?

Currently my system sends SMS using the Way2SMS-API and sends Email using gmail.

Answer (score 3):

Email is easy (relatively) to hack, as messages are sent plain and may be routed through many unknown servers.

SMS is more difficult, but not impossible.

However a combination of SMS and Email along with an expiry time (i.e. must complete login with 24 hours) should be considered secure enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach to address this is to require to enter secure token while original [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) in your web application is still active. So, even if hacker intercepts your message, he can't use it, because session is owned by the user (e.g. genrated token is stored in session attributes, so you can compare them when user will enter them on the web UI). Then the only way to intercept this would be to use a "man in a middle attack", but it can be defeated by using https.

Another approach would be to show user part of the key, so he have to re-enter it together with the part he'll receive in email. So, even if hacker steal that email, he won't be able to know what been shown to the user at the time email been generated.

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick response. But i didn't get your answer. Will you please try to elaborate more . Please i am a student so it may happen that i am not getting the things that you want to say. So can you explain me in simple words.

Comment: Not much to explain really. After you generated your tokens and sent them over email and SMS you can get instance of HttpSession from your servlet code and store those tokens using setAttribute(). When user enters those tokens back on the web UI, you get stored values from HttpSession and compare. A HttpSession instance is always linked with user connection (usually trough special request parameter or cookie value like jsessionid) so another user will have a different session, unless he steal that jsessionid value, but like I said, you can make it much more difficult by using https.

Comment: But what if session time out occur and user didn't enter the tokens with in session time out interval ? Means what i want to say when user will receive these tokens first off all he need to provide his email id and password for log in. After a successful login a new session is created then if account is not activated system asks for activation code. How i can bind my tokens to new session or that will be created in future .

Comment: For the first approach, the whole idea is that user gets validated without creating a new session. So, if session expires, he'll have to start over. With the second approach in my response you can create a new session, as it is based on a "secret" part that only user would know and that can't be intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use `Md5` and send half of it via sms and half via email then check it against the logged password's hashed value and if its right, allow them to register, otherwise, dont let them register. However, this is assuming that only one of the two (email/SMS) gets hacked. Otherwise, if they get both it would defeat the purpose.

@Eugine That is a good idea lol i didnt think of that one. ^.^

Comment: ya but entering a hash that a hex value will be more difficult for users.

Comment: It would be more difficult, however it would further security as opposed to a plaintext split as if you have half, you can brute force the other half of the plaintext password much more easily then brute forcing the other half of an md5 hash.

Comment: I am not splitting the password. I am generating a random alphanumeric string and then splitting it.

Comment: Ok, you could make a temporary dictionary for the user having the following (python dictionary example): `user={'Username':username,'Password':password,'Key':randkey,'hkey1':hashkey1,'hkey2':hkey2}` generate a random number, convert the random number to a string, then turn the string into an md5 hash, split the hash in two, and send them through email/sms. Then you can put them together and check it to your dictionary to confirm.

Comment: for `'hkey2':hkey2` i meant to put `'hkey2':hashkey2` :P

Comment: -1 for poor usability - most users would find this process quite difficult - I've never seen anything like this in practice.